# Scala StringView-like class

Tags: scala, scala-3

I want to see a class that represents a part of the existing string. Something that I can use in the following manner:

```
val theBigString: String = ???;
val pattern: Regex = ???;

val mySubstring = SmthLikeStringView(theBigString, /*start*/ 1000, /*end*/ 1500);
if (pattern.matches(mySubstring)) {???;} else {???;}
```

Of course I know about the following stuff, but it seems not to fit:

1. `val mySubstring = theBigString.substring(/*start*/ 1000, /*end*/ 1500)`. The resulting object has nice interface, which I like. But AFAIK, the operation implies literally copying character, which I want to avoid, I'd like to create a "lightweight" object.
2. `val mySubstring = scala.collection.StringView(theBigString).slice(/*start*/ 1000, /*end*/ 1500)`. This is really a `View` (hopefully, lightweight enough), but it has inappropriate interface. Not only it has unexpected method names (e.g. `slice` instead of `substring`), but it also doesn't implement `CharSequence`, so I can't operate on it via `Regex` and other standard ways.

Is there something that (on the one hand) is lightweight, view-like and (on the other hand) can be used together with `Regex`?

(AFAIK, no. But then the questions are: (1) WHY??? (2) Are there any bug reports / feature requests for that?)

Comment: I am pretty sure you can create your own class that extends `CharSequence` and implement it using the **View** of your second example. If you find this useful enough you may publish it as your own library or you may open a pull request in **Scala-library-next** or in **Scala-collection-contrib** _(check the READMES of both projects before submitting the PR)_

Comment: Once upon a time, `.substring` on `String` did not create a copy but a view. However, that was changed because it was causing memory leaks (getting very small substrings from very long strings like whole XML documents).